# Python 3 instead of python 2

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed python3 on my mac and already have python 2 installed.
How can I make python3 the default interpreter.
Using sublime text, I save the file with .py extension and notice it is referring to python 2,when first I see that f string throw an error and then when checking using sys.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make the default interpreter to Python 3 by using alias or by doing symbolic link but changing the default to Python3 may break applications which may use Python 2.

It is better to use pyenv to manage Python environments.

Install pyenv using Homebrew

$ brew install pyenv

$ pyenv install 3.8

$ pyenv global 3.8

Then add it to configuration file.

$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc

Reset the current shell and verify

$ exec $0

$ python -V

Please refer to this article, [The right and wrong way to set Python 3 as default on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) for more details.